# Bundler in staging while rails server/app in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

Weirdness: bundler is in staging, while rails app in development.

While working locally in development and calling "bundle exec rake db:migrate", bundler runs in staging not development.

The problem was first discovered today when doing a new migration: bundle exec rake db:migrate

Bundler could not connect to the database until I modified the database.yml, changing the staging db to be the same as the development db.

This app is three months old and has been working. Just started today.

rails app in development

rails s

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

From newrelic_agent.log upon starting server: rails s

```
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "development" environment.
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false environment variable or modify the "development" section of your newrelic.yml.
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Environment: development
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Dispatcher: thin
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Application: Launch More (Development)
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] WARN : Agent configured not to send data in this environment.
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation hooks
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Installing Dalli Memcache instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Installing Sinatra instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Installing Rails 3 Controller instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Installing Rails 3.1/3.2 view instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:20:51 (1648)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler sampler not available: No DJ worker present
[08/25/13 17:20:53 (1648)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "development" environment.
[08/25/13 17:20:53 (1648)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false environment variable or modify the "development" section of your newrelic.yml.
[08/25/13 17:20:53 (1648)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
```

From newrelic_agent.log upon calling: bundle exec rake db:migrate

```
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "staging" environment.
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false environment variable or modify the "staging" section of your newrelic.yml.
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] WARN : Agent is configured not to use SSL when communicating with New Relic's servers
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Environment: staging
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Dispatcher: thin
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Application: Launch More (Staging)
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation hooks
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Installing Dalli Memcache instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Installing Sinatra instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Installing Rails 3 Controller instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Installing Rails 3.1/3.2 view instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
[08/25/13 17:23:05 (1659)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler sampler not available: No DJ worker present
[08/25/13 17:23:06 (1659)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "staging" environment.
[08/25/13 17:23:07 (1659)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false environment variable or modify the "staging" section of your newrelic.yml.
[08/25/13 17:23:07 (1659)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
```

Any ideas as to why?

How to fix this?

Thanks, Mark

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ruby 1.9.3p202 (2012-04-27 revision 35484) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

Answer (score 0):

First: You should have some sort of source control. Has anything changed? Look back to the most recent commit that successfully allowed you to do what you're trying to do.

Next I would check to see if you have any environmental variables set that are specifically telling it to run in staging mode (RAILS_ENV). Also check your new_relic.yml file.

And finally, if both of those are negative, I would look further into your hosts configurations. Did they deploy some update to your environment?

Comment: Thanks Adam - checking to see if anything set "Rails.env = 'staging'" helped locate the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - such a bonehead move - but a GREAT LEARNING experience!

ISSUE: Whenever gem & Cronjob

In setting up the whenever gem to call different cron jobs in different environments, I was having issues.

Within development and staging to see cronjob you can run:

bundle exec whenever

But running "bundle exec whenever" within both environments showed "RAILS_ENV=production".

So in an attempt to solve this "RAILS_ENV=production" in staging and development, I setup separate cron jobs:

sitemap.rb
sitemap_staging.rb

... then within sitemap_stageing.rb included:

Rails.env = 'staging'

... I was thinking "Rails.env = 'staging'" would only be called when it was needed.

Lesson Learned... the "Rails.env = 'staging'" was being called and environment set when the app was initiated. Duh!

And when I ran "crontab -e", it showed the proper environments for development, staging, and  production:

When running "bundle exec whenever" it only shows "RAILS_ENV=production" - weird.

Thanks, Mark